# Is it possible to indent certain bits of texts within a label/button in kivy?

Tags: python, string, kivy, label, indentation

I am working on a code, that needs to display legal paragraphs. I want to display the paragraph with indented bits like this:
[Indented text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKSoX.jpg)
[indented example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcBwz.jpg)

but so far i only managed to display it like this:
[Not indented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE8Vf.jpg)
[Not indented 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UWKm.jpg)

Adding \t and reading the text in the label as unicode does not work. it only adds spaces in the first line but does not continue to indent in the next line. Same goes for ljust() and rjust()

Can anybody help me how to get text indented within a label/button in Kivy? So far could not find a solution anywhere else. The problem is that i dont know when the new line starts. Maybe knowing when the string is splitted in the new line and adding spaces there would solve the problem as well

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share the code that's not working? This will make easier for people here to understand what's going on.

Comment: the code is working fine so far. i just dont know how to indent pieces of text within a label. the code grabs the text of a legal paragraph and then i format it to be shown in a label. the only formatting that i dont know how to do is the indentation. i can only add spaces in the right spots of the string but i dont know how to get spaces after the string is put in the next line

Answer (score 1):

Try using Kivy Label's `Text Markup` feature. A label can be set into *markup* mode in two ways:

```
# python3
l = Label(text='Hello [b]World[/b]', markup=True)
```

```
# kv lang
Label:
    text: '[color=ff3333]Hello[/color][color=3333ff]World[/color]'
    markup: True
```

Markup allows you to use HTML-like syntax to style up Labels. See [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.text.markup.html) for all the different tags/options.